# Swing GridBagLayout placement

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

I'm having issues with placing my components the places I want them to be.

I want my explain_lbl to be in the upper left corner, then under it I want the NORM_lbl, and to the left of the NORM_lbl i want the NORM_bar. Under them I want the PTR_lbl... and so on. How do I do this?

```
GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

        pane.add(explain_lbl, gc);
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;

        pane.add(NORM_lbl, gc);
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;

        pane.add(NORM_bar, gc);
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 2; 

        pane.add(PTR_lbl, gc);
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;

        pane.add(PTR_bar, gc);
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;

        pane.add(btn_play, gc); 
        gc.gridx = 3; 
        gc.gridy = 3;
```

Comment: the lbl mean label and they have a loading bar beside each of them

Comment: It would be much better if you could provide a mock. How can you have in the upper left corner a label, and on the left of the label just below the first label a column?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: Without a mock of what you want to achieve it will be hard to help you, as describing a GUI with pure text is hard and it seems nobody could understand the GUI you want in the end...